# Adding another date field into my row level formula IF statement

Tags: lightning, formula, reporting

I currently have this row level formula which helps me work out if we have hit SLA on contact, but would like to add in another date/time field to this (attempted date/time) as well as first contact.

Every way ive tried seems to not work! here is the formula which works now,

```
IF(Opportunity.First_Contact_Date_Time__c - 
   Opportunity.Broker_Email_Sent_Date_Time__c < 24, 1, 0)
```

What I want is another level to it where if the first contact date time is blank, it will do the same calculation for the attempted date/time. So the formula if thinking would look like this; (but cant get it to work as im guessing im not putting it in the correct format!)

IF (Opportunity.First Contact Date Time__C OR Opportunity.Attempted Contact Date Time - Opportunity.Broker_Email_Sent_Date_Time__c < 24, 1, 0)

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community.  what do you mean by "calculation". Use [edit] - perhaps express in pseudo-code what you want

Comment: so id like it to provide a 1 or a 0 for the (first contact date time) - as it already does, but also provide a 1 or a 0 for another date column (attempted contact date time) does that make sense?

Comment: we need more details here - please use [edit] . What is the field name of this other field? what is the calculation with that field and does it have something to do with Broker Email Sent Date.

Comment: ive edited it now, hopefully that makes more sense. all 3 opportunity objects are all date/time fields,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following

```
IF(BLANKVALUE(Opportunity.First_Contact_Date_Time__c,
              Opportunity.Attempted_Contact_Date_Time__c) -
    Opportunity.Broker_Email_Sent_Date_Time__c < 24, 
   1, 0)
```

see [BLANKVALUE doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_blankvalue.htm&type=5)

Comment: This works - thank you so much - much appreciated!

Comment: as a service to the Community, please click the checkmark so others than easily see this question was answered

Answer (score 0):

What you'd need to do here is either leverage the AND()/OR() functions within formula fields, or use nested IF statements.

You can chain IF statements together, replacing your TRUE or FALSE values with another IF statement, like this:

IF(Argument,**True**,False)

IF(Argument,**IF(Argument,True,False)**,False)

So using your example, a starting point would be something like...

```
IF(
  NOT(
    ISBLANK(Opportunity.First_Contact_Date_Time__c)
  ),
  IF(
    Opportunity.First_Contact_Date_Time__c - Opportunity.Broker_Email_Sent_Date_Time__c < 24,
    1, 
    0
  ),
  IF(
    NOT(
        ISBLANK(Field_2__c)
    ),
    If_True_Here,
    If_False_Here
  )
)
```

Comment: thank you for responding so quickly, i've just added in the other field i need to add, how would i go about finishing this off? IF(
  NOT(
    ISBLANK(Opportunity.First_Contact_Date_Time__c)
  ),
  IF(
    Opportunity.First_Contact_Date_Time__c - Opportunity.Broker_Email_Sent_Date_Time__c < 24,
    1, 
    0
  ),
  IF(
    NOT(
        ISBLANK(Opportunity.Attempted_First_Contact_Date__c)

Comment: @JasonAppleton IF statements must always contain the Condition, the IF_TRUE value, and the IF_FALSE value. Your last IF statement only contains a condition, you need to add the first of the IF formula just like you would if you were using a non-nested IF.